# Python Bottle Framework - Plugin to Run Request in New Process (via multiprocessing)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, bottle

I have a fairly simple api built with the bottle framework.  One of the methods/routes in the api is CPU intensive.  For this reason, when this method is called, I would like to spawn a separate process with the standard Python multiprocessing module to side-step the GIL issues I currently see when the method is executed concurrently.

I realize that if this approach is very bad for a number of reasons - but its what I have to deal with right now.  Snippet below doesnt work.

```
def run_in_new_process(callback):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1)
        result = pool.apply_async(callback, (*args, **kwargs))
        return result.get()
    return wrapper
```

Comment: What error do you get? **Why** doesn't in work

Comment: i changed to this - result = pool.apply_async(callback,args=args).  but i get pickling error about the callback function

Comment: Data sent from one process to another, in this case the callback function, needs to be [picklable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled). Only functions defined at the top level of a module can be pickled, not functions defined within functions or methods.

Comment: did u got solution for this question?